# Why i am getting extra (1 row(s) affected)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

i am updating sql server table and updating only one record.but i am getting message (1 row(s) affected) so many times why so?
My query is as :

```
UPDATE V2HRMS.dbo.tbl_pm_employee
    SET LeavingDate='06-26-2013'
       ,Status=1 
WHERE EmployeeCode=3407
```

This is just for my knowledge.

Comment: The question this is marked as a duplicate of is NOT the same question. In that question the user indicates that they know triggers don't exist so that can't be the problem. This question makes no mention of it and an answer was provided explaining how to see if triggers are the source of the problem which it turned out was my problem. No answers in the previous question outline how to do this because it's already understood that can't be the cause.

Answer (score 6):

I think there are some trigger(s) defined on your table try executing the following statement to see if there are any triggers defined on your table:

```
SELECT SO.NAME, SC.[text]
FROM sysobjects SO INNER JOIN  syscomments SC
ON SO.ID = SC.ID
WHERE SO.[type] = 'TR'
AND SC.[text] LIKE '%tbl_pm_employee%'
```

Once you have found the trigger and if you do not want it executing when you are updating the table, use the following statement to disable and enable it:

**DISABLE TRIGGER**

```
DISABLE TRIGGER tr_Triggername ON tbl_pm_employee;
```

*Do your update here*

**ENABLE TRIGGER**

```
ENABLE TRIGGER tr_Triggername ON tbl_pm_employee;
```

Comment: I was trying to insert a large number of rows from a temporary table to a main table, but it was only inserting one row at a time. This was my issue. Leaving this comment so it hopefully pops up in search for other people.

Answer (score 6):

That usually means you have the `actual execution plan option` turned on. The execution plan is sent as an extra rowset, resulting in an **extra (1 row(s) affected)** message

To disable `actual execution plan` press **Ctrl+M**

Comment: Upvote : This was the reason I was seeing 'extra' insert items in output log. Nice tip!

Answer (score 2):

Your table has a trigger attached to it and so whenever you fire an update statement, the trigger is also getting fired and hence you get an extra message.

Comment: then why not all employeecodes i updated got same extra messages.some got only 1 message while other got extra messages??